# Class requires API level 11 (current min is 8)

Tags: android, mobile, sdk

I am new to Android Stuio. I created a project with the default setting and the added a fragment layout then fragment class

I am now getting the following error:

**Class requires API  level 11 (current min is 8)**

on this line:

public class WeatherFragment extends Fragment {

here is my import:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

and this is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jassim.yallabahrain.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.jassim.yallabahrain.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: hmm, i didn't know that [google.com](https://www.google.pl/search?q=Class+requires+API+level+11+(current+min+is+8)) is  not working....

Comment: [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments--mobile-5431) is the nice tutorial for implementing fragment in older device.hopefully it will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If you persist to use SDK version 8, I think that you must use [`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) instead `android.app.Fragment`.

It happened because `android.app.Fragment` is supported from Android SDK version +11 and if you want to use that you must use support library.

Answer (score 2):

Change your manifest as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jassim.yallabahrain.app" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jassim.yallabahrain.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't change your SDK in the manifest file, since the value always going to be overwritten by your "build.gradle" file (As specified in the **Issue id: GradleOverrides.**)

[image: GradleOverrides Error]

**Not only that, but if you try to insert your SDK in the manifest file, it won't even work:**

[image: GradleOverrides Error]

So, to fix that, try this method.

Go to your "build.gradle" file, and add this to your "defaultConfig".

```
defaultConfig{

   minSdkVersion 15
   targetSdkVersion 28

}
```

[image: defaultConfig]

After that, remove the SDK you inserted into your manifest file, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

add following lines in your manifest.xml before application tag starts.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Comment: When using the gradle build, set `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `build.grade` instead of the `<uses-sdk>` element in `AndroidManifest.xml`. [*Still,* Android Studio 0.6.1 is warning that some layout resources "requires API level 11 (current min is 1)" even though it's set to 13.]

Answer (score 0):

Basically the feature you want to use requires a minimal API that is not guaranteed in your current `Manifest` file. You have to make sure it is set because any user that runs your app might have problems if they use a lower API for the one that's made your app.

You have to include a statement like this in your Manifest file to ensure the users will be running a minimal API of 11 (and by the way make your code compile).

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jassim.yallabahrain.app" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jassim.yallabahrain.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are quite right but they don't explain why this is happening, the cause of the error is that you need at least API level 11 (Android 3.0). This is needed because the usage of Fragments in your API. Fragments were introduced in the 3.0 version. So if you want to allow devices with an Android version below than 3.0 you can not use Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in your manifest:
While changing the minimal sdk version to 11, will help resolving your error...

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"    
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your minSdkVersion to 11 in Manifest as below. I hope it will help:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.s1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
```

Answer (score -1):

change your manifest to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jassim.yallabahrain.app" >

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.jassim.yallabahrain.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```